# Change default input language in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

> I want to change my default input language in as3! (alt + shift)
>
> can everyone help me?
>
> thanks.

Comment: have you tried google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default language has nothing to do with AS3/Flash - it is OS dependent

A solution might work is to create a map of all the keyboard in the 2 languages you want to handle and replace each occurrence of a key from the unwanted language - to the respective one in the other language.
of course this kind of solution has its own problems - (e.g. Pasting text with Ctrl+V) - which you can handle in `Event.CHANGE` (or `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` event on the desired `TextField`